# Mocha test with data layer?

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js

I have a question about data layer in mocha/should test.

I allready have a test.js which contains the mocha/should test.

**The following is what im supposed to do with this:**
Write tests in Mocha/Should + a sufficient mock-framework (nock will do the job) that should verify that the data layer call the correct URLs in the Rest API. The tests should not invoke the underlying Rest API.

I have a simple Rest api with CRUD.
Im not sure what to put in my data layer?

```
//setup tests var
var testUserEquals = {
url: "http://localhost:3000/api/users/:email",
method: 'GET'
};

var testUserEmail = {
url: "http://localhost:3000/api/users/ultricies.adipiscing@utaliquam.ca",
method: 'GET',
json: true
};

//and a test for email:
    describe('get a specific user with email', function(){
    it('should return a specific user', function(done){

        //facade her
        request(testUserEmail, function(err, res, body){
            if(err){
                throw err;
            }
            body.email.should.equal("ultricies.adipiscing@utaliquam.ca");
            done();
        })
    })
})
```

In my users.js i just have some emails and password:

```
module.exports = [
 {
"email": "ultricies.adipiscing@utaliquam.ca",
"password": "0B25A444-D4BC-8819-3632-D38626487588"
 }]
```

And finally my data layer, which i call control.js

```
var user = require('./users');

function getUser(email, callback){
user.findUser(function(err, user){
    if(err)
    return callback(err);
    console.log(user);
})
};
```

Im a little lost on what my datalayer should contain, and couldn´t find any info about it anywhere.

Comment: I re-read your question twice, I honestly don't know what you're asking.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to test (with mocha)? It seem you're trying to test an Express route end-piont (based on the [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) in your test. If that's the case, where's the Express route handler? If it's not the case, my question stands: What re you trying to test?

Comment: Wups sorry about the quick question. Yes im going to test the API. And have a real simple rest with: `app.get("/api/users/:email", function(req, res) {
    var user = findUser(users, req.params.email);
    if(!user) {
        return res.status(404).send({error: "user not found"});
    }
    res.send(user);
});` I must write a data layer which must use(call) the REST api with getUser(email, callback) but i dont know what it should contain.

Comment: And it says that i should Write tests in Mocha/Should + a sufficient mock-framework (nock will do the job) that should verify that the data layer call the correct URLs in the Rest API. The tests should not invoke the underlying Rest API.

Comment: Your question is still quite difficult to understand. If this is an assignment, can you post more concrete instructions? (I'm assuming it's an assignment because you wrote "and it says I should ...")